# Resolving many to many relationship

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, relationship

I have 3 tables that i am trying to figure out how to set the relationships.  The database is to track survey questions and answers.  A User can answer many questions, A question can have many answers, An answer can be associated with only one question. An answer can be used by many users.

USER: UserId, name, etc....

ANSWER: Answer id, AnswerText, QuestionId

QUESTION: QuestionId, QuestionText

I'm thinking of adding a table to break is up:

USER_QUESTION_ANSWER: id, AnswerId, QuestionId, Userid

Answerid, questionid and userid would all be FKs to the respective tables.  However this seems incorrect.  It seems it should just be:

QUESTION_ANSWER: id, QuestionId, Answerid

but the problem I run into is I need to track what user gave what answers.  The ANSWER table already tracks what answers go to what questions.  Should I add2 new tables?

USER_ANSWER: id, Userid, Answerid

QUESTION_ANSWER: id, QuestionId, Answerid

Comment: Having had one job at a educational facility, I would use a different name.  An "Answer" is something a Question has.  A "Response" is something a User selects when he/she is taking the test.  "Answer" and "Score" are some of hte most ambiguous names in the educational industry.  On the Question "which one of these is a mammal?", with possible answers "BlueJay, Cobra, Perch, and Dog", John ~responded with "Dog".  His ~response~ was correct because it matched the correct Answer..................Ambiguity causes more issues than we all realize I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick with the `USER_QUESTION_ANSWER` table personally.  It's not 100% normalized because you have the `QuestionId` in the `ANSWER` table as well as the `USER_QUESTION_ANSWER` table but that type of de-normalization isn't unusual.  It makes for easier queries and reporting.  Your PRIMARY KEY on `USER_QUESTION_ANSWER` will be on the `UserId, AnswerId` columns since as far as uniqueness goes the `QuestionId` is irrelevant.

Basically what you are going to end up with is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 4 tables: USER, QUESTION, ANSWER (Id, description) and the table how's record the relationship: UQA (id user, id question, id answer)

Easy to count (how many answers by user) and distinct (one user with many questions with one answer by question)